# Numbering the output lines of an awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I used the `awk` command to get the list of users from /etc/passwd. Now I want to number it, this is the command I used but it doesn't seem to work, how do I get it to work?

```
s=0
awk -F':' '{s+=1} END {print "USER"$s" = " $1}' /etc/passwd
```

I expect it to output:

```
USER1 = xyz
USER2 = abc
```

And so on

Comment: not actually what you want, just an idea: `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | nl`

Comment: `pr -n -l1 -t /etc/passwd` would give you line numbered output (without the USER prefix).  `nl` doesn't number blank lines, which shouldn't be a problem with `/etc/passwd`, but can be a problem in other contexts (and can be what's desired in still other contexts).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: `nl -ba` will number all the lines

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you only get one result line is that your print matches only one single line (the last) because you use the [`END`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html) keyword.

You don't need to set `s=0` in your shell as variables are handled by awk itself. And as @JonathanLeffler mentions, `$` selects a field in awk. So `$s` will not be replaced by the value of variable `s`, but by the field `s`, where `s` is the variable value. (if `s == 2`, you'd print field number 2.)

Try this:

```
# Start with 0 (using an extra variable s)
awk -F':' '{print "USER"s++" = " $1}' /etc/passwd

# Start with 1 (using the internal variable NR)
awk -F':' '{print "USER"NR" = " $1}' /etc/passwd

# Produce sortable output for further processing
awk -F':' '{printf "USER%04d=%s\n", NR-1, $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Thanks to the commenters for more ideas.

Comment: and to get sortable `USER${N}` values, maybe the O.P. would use `printf("USER%04d=%s\n", ++s, $1)` (not mentioned as a criteria, but often a follow-up ;-) ). . Good luck to all.

Comment: I'd suggest in both cases that you use `++s` to start at 1 as per the OP's intention, or perhaps just to use `NR`.

Comment: Yes, I mean the user may have a further need for this data, and without zero padding it will be sorted as USER1, USER10, USER11, USER2, USER3, etc. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when I was doing what I mentioned in the question I was getting just 1 line as an output, why is that?

Comment: @steffen just a hint, instead of an extra variable, we might simply use `NR` since it is already constantly growning.

Comment: @AnubhabSen: You had a single `print` operation in the `END` block, so the only printing occurred at the end of the input.  Further, the `print "USER"$s" = "$1` would try to print the field of the last input record corresponding to the number of records found in the file (`$s` means the field number identified by variable `s`).